# Type new line character in Element.TextContent

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to generate a textual content in a web application. I want a text to appear into a header element `<h1>` but the text must contain newline breaks.

### First attempt

```
var el = document.getElementById("myel");
var newline = "\r\n";
var nbsp = "\u00a0";
el.textContent = "My awesome" + newline + "web" + nbsp + "application";
```

This is not working. I mean in the developer tools, by inspecting the DOM, I can see the text being broken between `"awesome"` and `"web"`, but the browser does not render it that way: the text is all on the same line but at least the non breaing space (which is correctly rendered like `&nbsp`) is there.

### Trying `<br/>`.

If I try to use `<br/>`, I must use `innerHTML`:

```
var el = document.getElementById("myel");
var newline = "<br/>";
var nbsp = "&nbsp";
el.innerHTML = "My awesome" + newline + "web" + nbsp + "application";
```

So there is no way I can get my problem solved by using `textContent`? I would really like avoiding `innerHTML`.

Comment: The `\r\n` sign is only seen in the code view mode. It is a line break for a code not for an HTML. Afaik you cannot create line breaks by setting the `textContent` of an element. Only if the text get the end of line.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use CSS [**`white-space: pre;`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space#Values) with `"\r\n"`:

```js
var el = document.getElementById("myel");
var newline = "\r\n";
var nbsp = "\u00a0";
el.textContent = "My awesome" + newline + "web" + nbsp + "application";
```

```css
#myel {
  white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<h1 id="myel"></h1>
```

Comment: You can also achieve this using JavaScript by using `el.style.whiteSpace = "pre";` if for some reason you do not wish to make changes in your CSS file.

Comment: Great hack. I like this one.