# How do I format a string from python to javascript to HTML mantaining python format character

Tags: javascript, python

I am trying to reformat a string that come form python pass to Javascript and end in html.

String: = "Hi how \n are you"

I am using the following command in Javascript

```
HTML.textContent = String.text
```

HTML is the name of the tag where the the String.txt will be rendered.
The problem is that the "\n" syntax present in python to "go newline" is not maintained

I am trying the following command to reformat

```
my_content = myquestion.text.replace("\n","NL")
```

where the \n shoul be replace with NL that should indicate new line.
I mean that \n should be replace by "< b r >" in html

Comment: Did you mean `<br>`?  That would make sense.  `myquestion.text.replace('\n','<br>')`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Type new line character in Element.TextContent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31002593/type-new-line-character-in-element-textcontent)